# cannot login to MySQL remotely

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, logins, connectivity, remote

users and root can log in locally with no problems. No user can login from a remote connection though

from remote:

```
[root@yoda:~] # mysql -v --host=r2d2.er.com --user=power --password='burp' power
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'power'@'yoda.er.com' (using password: YES)
```

from server:

```
mysql> show grants for power@'yoda.er.com';     
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for power@yoda.er.com                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'power'@'yoda.er.com' |
+----------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show grants for power@'18.61.10.64';
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for power@18.61.10.64                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'power'@'18.61.10.64' |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)



mysql> show grants for power@'%.er.com';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for power@%.ex-mailer.com                                                                                                              |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'power'@'%.er.com' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*333333333333333333333333333333' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There are no errors in the logs other than access denied. There is no firewall and other services like apache work just fine. Port 3306 is live. (obviously if there are denied logs)
How do I find what is preventing a remote login to mysql?

UPDATE:
my.cnf

```
[root@r2d2 ~]# locate my.cnf
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf
[root@r2d2 ~]# cat /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

[mysqld]

relay-log=r2d2-relay-bin
log-bin=mysql-bin
server-id=1
general_log_file=/var/log/query.log
max_allowed_packet = 10M
innodb_data_home_dir = /var/db/mysql/
innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:10M:autoextend
innodb_log_group_home_dir = /var/db/mysql/
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
#innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
innodb_log_file_size = 5M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50

#replication stuff
log_bin = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
binlog_do_db = powerdns
ssl-key=/home/opensslkeys/server.key
ssl-cert=/home/opensslkeys/server.crt
ssl-ca=/home/opensslkeys/ca.key
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1

bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

system info:

```
[root@r2d2 ~]# freebsd-version
10.1-RELEASE-p5

[root@r2d2 ~]# mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";'
Enter password: 
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| Variable_name           | Value               |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
| innodb_version          | 5.6.27              |
| protocol_version        | 10                  |
| slave_type_conversions  |                     |
| version                 | 5.6.27-log          |
| version_comment         | Source distribution |
| version_compile_machine | amd64               |
| version_compile_os      | FreeBSD10.1         |
+-------------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: not sure, but for start: You have in command line 2 user names - --user=powerdns --password='burp' power. AND powerdns AND power, try simple - mysql --host=r2d2.er.com -u power -p

Comment: Can you show output from SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user; ?

Comment: @a_vlad  question edit. It's not a syntax issue.  But I am also not going to be foolish enough to publish my actual user names on the www. I forgot that 1 single edit.  No, that is not the issue.

Comment: @CraigEfrein  Yes, select and local login works fine. As indicated in the original question/post.

Comment: In the my.cnf, are you skipping resolve-dns ?

Comment: @CraigEfrein  I added the contents of my.cnf to the question as an update.

Comment: Not sure if this is a freebsd issue or otherwise. Somehow the user/password/host information is not being received as expected by yoda.er.com. Or the users you're creating on yoda.er.com aren't in the format you're expecting them in.

Comment: @CraigEfrein can you add your answer back?  You were correct, It an enduser error. I don't know if this in new or a setting I have without knowing but, adding an IP grant means no password needed (for years it was to have any access at all). You were very correct to keep hammering at different login methods.

Comment: Hi @doeJ glad to hear I was able to help. When logging in locally without a password, you are probably doing so using the unix socket file and not tcp. I was hammering the different login methods to show you all the different ways I test logins when one particular method fails. I'll update my answer with this info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be a result of how you are defining your users.  I don't think the wildcards are working as you're expecting them to. The best way to figure this out, in my opinion, is to create a new user and password for the 18.61.10.64 host on the yoda.er.com MySQL Server.

Keep in mind that when logging in locally, the MySQL client on your server might be using the unix socket to authenticate.

```
mysql> show variables like '%socket%';
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                       |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| socket        | /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
```

[Connecting to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connecting.html)

If this is the case then a password isn't necessary when logging in locally onto the MySQL server.

Could you try this from the machine you are trying to connect to. Use a new user and password combination because we are not sure how many different entries you might have for your power user.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'18.61.10.64' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'somepassword';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then from the shell on 18.61.10.64

```
mysql -u someuser -h ip.address.for.r2d2.er.com -psomepassword
```

Comment: Efein    same issue brother   https://paste.ee/p/JNomO

Comment: right but I wanted you to connect like this mysql -h ip.address.for.r2d2.er.com. Also you didn't FLUSH PRIVILEGES in your example

Comment: I flushed privileges and rebooted server  https://paste.ee/p/bRkpq  and tried to connect via IP, it returns same error using fqdn

Comment: show variables like '%skip%'; in MySQL console on r2d2.er.com

Comment: Efein FYI, I had tried every grant option possible prior to posting. I'm pretty sure it's not that.  I mean, it is that, but something is miswired and normal stuff isn't working. Like some wildly bad setting in my.cnf, but I can't figure out what. It 'did' work before. I had replication working fine but needed SSL. since SSL implementation attempt, it's be messed up.

Comment: http://paste.ee/p/xz5Jr   %skip%   output

Comment: You wrapped your password in quotes, have you just tried mysql -v --host=17.11.60.48 --user=power -pfart power or simply mysql -v -h 17.11.60.48 -u power -p power

Comment: the real password has naughty characters that in some cases need to be escaped. the single quotes are completely ignored (but not in php world and other habits of mine). Yes, I tried without quotes.

Comment: The only other test would be to enter the password in upon connection. In other words with just -p and no password mysql -v -h 17.11.60.48 -u power -p power. No other suggestions after this.

Comment: Try a user other than power, which you may have multiple entries for on 17.11.60.48. Create a whole new user/password combination

Answer (score -1):

Check if server is listening on port 3306 which is the default port. Check if bind-address option is enabled in my.cnf and disable it. Lastly, check firewall on the server.

Comment: server already return error - ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'power'@'yoda.er.com' (using password: YES)
so, problem not in the connection

Comment: As stated in original post, port 3306 is live.  Firewall is completely disabled.